# How to set ContextMenu option in ListViewCommand Set in SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

In spfx listview command set, I want to add a new context menu option to list items. I have this

elements.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <CustomAction
        Title="ImagePicker"
        RegistrationId="100"
        RegistrationType="List"
        Location="ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet.ContextMenu"
        ClientSideComponentId="e15a3da8-5684-44f5-abc8-e9c72f5bb926"
        ClientSideComponentProperties="{&quot;sampleTextOne&quot;:&quot;One item is selected in the list.&quot;, &quot;sampleTextTwo&quot;:&quot;This command is always visible.&quot;}">
    </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

and clientsideinstance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <ClientSideComponentInstance
        Title="ImagePicker"
        Location="ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet.ContextMenu"
        ListTemplateId="100"
        Properties="{&quot;sampleTextOne&quot;:&quot;One item is selected in the list.&quot;, &quot;sampleTextTwo&quot;:&quot;This command is always visible.&quot;}"
        ComponentId="e15a3da8-5684-44f5-abc8-e9c72f5bb926" />
</Elements>
```

but when I test on gulp serve, it only appears in the top command bar, not on the list item. Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Check [this](https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/step-by-step-procedure-to-create-custom-context-menu-in-edit-control-block-using-spfx-extension-in-sharepoint-modern-lists/). Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of "location" in your config/serve.json file.